# Developer console can't save

Tags: developer-console

It seems I can't save anything using developer console, Class, Page etc.

I update a file and then I hit save. something I get this error but most of the time it just stays at the saving... state.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Console uses the Tooling API to save Apex and VF. 
The Tooling API saves these entities by using a MetatdataContainer and MetatdataContainerMembers. The errors don't make much sense to me, but it looks like the console is in a bad state.

1.) You can try to create a New Workspace and switch to it.

2.) Clear the container members (or container) every time you open the developer console, which is a hassle. (You can delete them by using Tooling API)

Comment: I've already tried creating new workspace but no luck. but how can I clear the container member ?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete MetadataContainer records either using Tooling API or via UI.

Access the list page for the MetadataContainer objects, like https://mydomain.salesforce.com/1dc

- Create a view that displays the "Container Name" field for all MetadataContainer objects
  ** the number of MetadataContainer objects is limited so there will never be more than a page of them
- Identity objects with matching "Container Name" fields and delete the older one or try to edit and you will know the ID in the URL which is failing with the duplicate value.

Let me know if it helps!